# x86 Assembly Compare Arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly

I'm using visual studio and calling assembly from C++. I know that when you pass an argument to assembly the first argument is in ECX and the second is in EDX. Why can't I compare the two registers directly without first copying ECX to EAX?

C++:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int PassingParameters(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "The function returned: " << PassingParameters(5, 10) << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

ASM: This gives the wrong value when comparing the two registers directly.

```
.code
PassingParameters proc
    cmp edx, ecx
    jg ReturnEAX

    mov eax, edx

ReturnEAX:
    ret
PassingParameters endp
end
```

But if I write it like this I get the correct value, and can compare the two registers directly, why is this?

```
.code
PassingParameters proc
    mov eax, ecx ; copy ecx to eax.
    cmp edx, ecx ; compare ecx and edx directly like above, but this gives the correct value.
    jg ReturnEAX

    mov eax, edx

ReturnEAX:
    ret
PassingParameters endp
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first version if the `jg` is taken, you're leaving `eax` exactly as it was upon entry to the function (i.e., we pretty much have no clue). Since the return value will normally be in eax, that's going to give an undefined return whenever the `jg` is taken. In other words, what you've written is roughly like:

```
int PassingParameters(int a, int b) { 
    if (a < b)
        return a;
}
```

In this case, if `a==b`, or `a>b`, your return value is garbage.

In the second code sequence, you're loading one value into eax. Then, if the jg not taken, you're loading the other value into eax. Either way, the return value will be one input parameter or the other (depending on which is greater). In other words, what you have is roughly equivalent to:

```
int PassingParameters(int a, int b) { 
   if (a<b)
       return a;
    return b;
}
```

P.S. I would also note that your code looks like x86, not 64-bit code at all. For 64-bit code, you should be using RAX, RCX, etc., rather than EAX, ECX, and such.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it 100% now.